# date intervals of 15 minutes between 9-5

Tags: php, select, for-loop

heres my code, all i want to do is echo the values so they come up in a SELECT input in the following format:

9:00
9:15
9:30
9:45
10:00
10:15
ETC.

heres my code which just crashes the page:

```
<select>
<option>Select Time</option>
<?php

for ($i = 9; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
    for ($j = 0; $j <= 45; $j+15)
    {
        echo '<option>'.$i.':'.str_pad($j, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';
    }
}

?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong $j increment. You should use this:

```
$j+=15
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not properly incrementing the `$j` loop:

Do this:

```
<?php

for ($i=9;$i<=12;$i++){
  for ($j=0;$j<=45;$j=$j+15)
      {
        echo '<option>'.$i.':'.str_pad($j, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';
      }
  }

?>
```

Comment: What about `$j += 15`? We are not in a lame language like VB6 ;)